# Trying to redirect the output of two commands to a txt file

Tags: windows, redirect, cmd, output

Trying to pull a list of laptop serials for inventory. The first command lists the serials successfully but leaves out the computer names.

```
for /f %A in (CompNames.txt) do wmic /user:user /password:pass /node:"%A" bios get serialnumber >> serials.txt
```

This second command does list the names and serials but it adds a bunch of spaces and the output is not easy to read. It is not in a list but just a few very long lines.

```
for /f %A in (CompNames.txt) do echo "%A" >> serials.txt & wmic /user:user /password:pass /node:"%A" bios get serialnumber >> serials.txt
```

How can I get the list like in the first command but with the computer names listed as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /f %A in (CompNames.txt) do wmic /user:user /password:pass /node:"%A" bios get serialnumber /format:csv >> serials.txt
```

Comment: Didn't even need the "echo". Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0):

The for loop is unnecessary.

`WMIC` can process it's own text files.

```
wmic /node:@c:\computernames.txt BIOS get serialnumber /format:hform
```

@ means the node is a textfile of computernames (without `\\`) and/or ip addresses.

```
127.0.0.1
serenity
192.0.0.1
```

For format try

list
table
xml
csv
hform (an html list)
htable (an html table)

some formats lists the node as well as the wmic data.

While you can use redirection with `wmic`, wmic has two command line switches `/output:` and `/append:` (Clip will do clipboard `/append:clip`). NB `Output` sends to file, `append` appends to file AND sends to screen.